# PHP Read CSS @import files

Tags: php, css, import

If I have a CSS file (main.css) with the following content:

```
@import url('../styles/global/reset.css');
@import url('/styles/themes/helloWorld/structure.css');
@import url('/styles/themes/helloWorld/presentation.css');
```

Is it possible to create a PHP file that is give the location of main.css and have it read all of the imported files?

I assume, I start with something like this:

```
$handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/styles/themes/helloWorld/main.css', 'r');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try PHP CSS Parser  - https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

```
$oCssParser = new CSSParser(file_get_contents('somefile.css'));
$oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();
```

Comment: So, I'm a PHP newbie :/
The [documents](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) say to "use getContents(), then iterate over that collection and use instanceof to check whether you’re dealing with another CSSImport"
I have the following:
`$oCssParser = new CSSParser(file_get_contents('import.test.css'));
$oCssDocument = $oCssParser->parse();
getContents($oCssDocument);`
Any chance you could provide some more assistance? THX

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve the problem with strpos() to find "@import url(" and substr() to extract the filename. Then you could just get the content of the files with file_get_contents(). Also, if you pass the last position of strpos() as the offset-variable you will find the next occurrence after the last one.